# Access a controller from a different controller ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs6

I'm just trying to call a method of a controller from a different controller using ExtJS 6.

Controller I'm trying to access: `Org.Application.summary.view.sample.SampleController`

How I've tried accessing it from a different controller:

```
var one = Org.Application.app.getController('Org.Application.summary.view.sample.SampleController');
var two = this.getApplication().getController('Org.Application.summary.view.sample.SampleController').getOOP();
var three = Org.Application.getController('Org.Application.summary.view.sample.SampleController').getOOP();
```

in my main `build.gradle` file it shows `project.ext.set( "rtdms.application.name", "Application" )` Not sure if that is supposed to be the application name.

Errors for each line respectively:

> Unable to get property 'getController' of undefined or null reference
>
> Object doesn't support property or method 'getApplication'
>
> Object doesn't support property or method 'getController'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the controller you are looking for is attached to a child or parent component you can find like so:

```
this.getView().down('somextype').getController();
this.getView().up('somextype').getController();
```

if you include a reference config in the component it is attached to you can use lookup reference:

```
this.lookupReference('myreference');
```